# Find the value between two ranges in xml file of one particular tag

Tags: xml

I have xml file where having tags `<a>0000123</a>`, `<a>1200000</a>`, `<a>0001000</a>`.

I need to get only the value which this particular tag should be between 100 to 1000.

Comment: tag will be in format of <a>0000123</a>

Comment: So the tags are `a` tags (_all_ `a` tags?) and their _values_ is what you want to find? Do you want copies of those tags or do you just need the actual values?

Comment: Please edit your question and add a xml example

Answer (score 1):

Using [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/):

```
xml sel -t -v '//a[. > 100 and . < 1000]' -nl file.xml
```

This will return a list of values between 100 and 1000. These values will be taken from the values of the `a` nodes of the XML document in `file.xml`, regardless of where these appear. Zero-filled numbers seems to be handled properly. The `-nl` at the end ensures that the output's last line has a newline at the end.

On some systems, XMLStarlet is installed as `xmlstarlet` instead of just `xml`.

Example:

```
$ cat file.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <a>0000123</a>
  <a>1200000</a>
  <a>0001000</a>
</root>

$ xml sel -t -v '//a[. > 100 and . < 1000]' -nl file.xml
0000123
```

Comment: In my case (kubuntu 17.10, bash) the command of the xmlstarlet package is `xmlstarlet` instead of `xml`. Works like a charme and does not look too complicated ;)

Answer (score 1):

With [xmllint](/questions/tagged/xmllint) :

```
xmllint --xpath '//a[text() > 100 and text() < 1000]/text()' file.xml
```

If you want to separate with newlines :

```
xmllint --shell file.xml <<< 'xpath //a[text() > 100 and text() < 000]/text()' |
    grep -oP 'content=\K.*'
```

AFAIK, it's a limitation of using `xmllint` without the switch `--shell`

Comment: How do you separate the result? for example by nl or whitespace ...

Comment: Check my edited post

Comment: As far as I could figure out, the output (without visual) separation is a correct xpath expression. A XSLT transformation could be the solution (http://compgroups.net/comp.text.xml/xmllint-xpath-add-new-line-to-output/2134897). Great answer anyway!